# MFP 8 - error parsing JSON object when using MobileFirst Push API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the following error when I tried to used the push API to send a notification. The JSON object works in version V7.1

```
{
  "code": "FPWSE0011E",
  "message": "Bad Request - The JSON validation failed at 'target'.",
  "productVersion": "8.0.0.00-20161122-1902"
}
```

Here is my JSON object

```
{
  "message": {
    "alert": "hello"
  },
  "settings": {
    "apns": {
      "badge": 1,
      "iosActionKey": "Ok",
      "payload": {
          "messageType": "HELLO",
            "detail": "Here's your message details."
      },
      "sound": "song.mp3"
    },
    "gcm": {
      "payload": {},
      "sound": "song.mp3"
    }
  },
  "target": {
    "consumerIds": [],
    "deviceIds": ["4A1086CF-873A-4404-BE2D-200EA6BDA8AD"],
    "platforms": [
      "A","G"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using the admin RestAPi interface

```
https://myserver/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/notifications/applications/com.myjobs/messages
```

I followed the format from the documentation
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_send_message_post.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the v8.0 documentation only 1 property is allowed in `target`.  In your JSON I see several properties are defined.

See example JSON here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#sending-notifications

And as can be seen:

```
target" : {
    // The list below is for demonstration purposes only - per the documentation only 1 target is allowed to be used at a time.
    "deviceIds" : [ "MyDeviceId1", ... ],
    "platforms" : [ "A,G", ... ],
    "tagNames" : [ "Gold", ... ],
    "userIds" : [ "MyUserId", ... ],
},
```